# MS Graph API: Assign planner tasks to other users

Tags: c#, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I'm looking to create a background application that can create/assign tasks/buckets/.. to people of my organisation.
I've created the app, gave (admin) permissions and was able to assign tasks to myself. But this was after getting a token with my own credentials.

Example code:

```
var graphClient = GetAuthenticatedClient();
PlannerBucket plannerbucket = new PlannerBucket();
plannerbucket.Name = "test bucket";
plannerbucket.PlanId = "****";
var addedBucket = graphClient.Planner.Buckets.Request().AddAsync(plannerbucket).Result;
```

Now I'm wondering if it's possible to assign tasks to other people using GraphServiceClient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign tasks to anyone in your organization. You still need a token with user credentials to make a request (Planner currently does not support app-only requests), but you can specify the assignee to be the id of any user in your organization to assign the task to that person, even if the token was created by someone else's credentials (e.g. yours).

Comment: Ok, I will try that!
Is there a way to get all the ID's of the users in my organization?

Comment: There are several ways to get to the user ids depending on your scenario and what you have. Do you have the UPN? /users/<upn> will return the user object. You can also pass UPN directly to Planner when it needs a user id, but it won't return back UPN. You can also get to the user ids by their relationships to other user and objects. For example, you could query organization starting with you with me/directReports or me/manager. All objects related to users in Graph will also have some sort of user id exposed from them. The docs should help: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/

Comment: I had found the solution, but thanks for the information!